# socketIO - Mapping a socket to a connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

**This question title was really worded incorrectly, but I have no idea how to word it. If anyone wants to edit it, please feel free.**

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to get a specific instance of a player via the socket that the data came from, this is going to be used to relay movements through my server for my small 2d project. Currently I have an object that's storing all of the players by the identification number, some  people say it's an object, some say it's a hashmap implementation, some say it's an array, whatever the hell it is, I'm using it.

```
var connectedPlayers = {};
```

When a connection is created I create a new player like so:

```
var playerId = Math.floor(Math.random()*(50000-1+1)+1);
var userId = Math.floor(Math.random()*(50000-1+1)+1);
var player = new Player(playerId, "Guest"+userId, socket);
connectedPlayers[playerId] = player;
```

Obviously this is just generating random names/identification numbers for now, but that's perfectly fine, this is executed  on the `socket.on('connection', function()` call.

If you need to see the Player.js script it's just a basic prototype script which sends information to all players about the player logging in, this all works properly.

```
var playerId;

var playerName;

var socket;

var positionX, positionY;

function Player(playerId, playerName, socket) {
    this.playerId = playerId;
    this.playerName = playerName;
    this.socket = socket;
    this.positionX = 250;
    this.positionY = 250;
    socket.emit('login', { playerID: playerId, playerX: this.positionX, playerY: this.positionY, playerName: playerName});
    socket.broadcast.emit('player-connected',{ playerID: playerId, playerX: this.positionX, playerY: this.positionY, playerName: playerName} )
}

Player.prototype.getId = function() {
    return this.playerId;
};

Player.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.playerName;
};

Player.prototype.getSocket = function() {
    return this.socket;
};

Player.prototype.getX = function() {
    return this.positionX;
};

Player.prototype.getY = function() {
    return this.positionY;
};
```

My problem is, I need to be able to find out which Player belongs to a socket when the data comes in, because I want to authoritatively send movements to the clients. To do this I need to not give the client any control when it comes to which playerId it contains, because if I let the client tell the server, we could have other players moving at random.

The only way I've thought of is something like this, but it doesn't seem very efficient.

```
for(var i in connectedPlayers) {
     if(conntectedPlayers[i].getSocket() == socket) {
          // do stuff
     }
}
```

**EDIT: Adding the entire sockets.on('connection') due to a request from comments.**

```
socketIO.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connection maid.");
    socket.on('login', function(json) {
        sqlConnection.query('select * FROM Accounts', function(err, rows, fields) {
            if(err) throw err;
            for(var row in rows) {
                if(rows[row].Username == json.username) {
                    var playerId = Math.floor(Math.random()*(50000-1+1)+1);
                    var player = new Player(playerId, "Guest"+playerId, socket);
                    connectedPlayers[playerId] = player;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    socket.on('move-request', function(json) {
        socket.emit('move-request', {x: json.x, y: json.y, valid: true});
    });

});
```

Comment: Where's the code when the socket connects?  Usually, you just do that inside a closure that has access to other data and put your other functions that receive data in their too.  Or, alternatively you can just add any property you want to the `socket` object that would identify it for you.  A separate hash is not needed.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I added it to the bottom.

Comment: So, is your question that you want to know which player it is when a message arrives on the server or in the client?

Comment: @jfriend00 - I want to know which player it is when the message arrives at the server, without sending any information from the client. I want to find the player that's associated with the socket.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add one or more properties to the socket object upon connection:

```
socketIO.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connection maid.");
    socket.on('login', function(json) {
        sqlConnection.query('select * FROM Accounts', function(err, rows, fields) {
            if(err) throw err;
            for(var row in rows) {
                if(rows[row].Username == json.username) {
                    var playerId = Math.floor(Math.random()*(50000-1+1)+1);
                    var player = new Player(playerId, "Guest"+playerId, socket);
                    connectedPlayers[playerId] = player;
                    // add custom properties to the socket object
                    socket.player = player;
                    socket.playerId = playerId;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    socket.on('move-request', function(json) {
        // you can access socket.playerId and socket.player here
        socket.emit('move-request', {x: json.x, y: json.y, valid: true});
    });
});
```

So, now anytime you get an incoming message on a socket, you then have access to the `playerId` and `player`.  In your code, when a message arrives, the `socket` variable for this message is in your parent scope and accessible so you can then get the `player` and `playerId`.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this situation a few times when storing "objects" in a C hash.  I use a 32 bit hash function specifically tailed for pointers.

I'm not sure what you could use to uniquely identify the socket instance and suggest you see what underlying fields exist for that purpose.  If you do find something that uniquely identifies the socket, you can feed that into a hash algorithm to generate a key.  Of course, you would need a hash implementation (most likely in JavaSCript from the looks of it).  I found this: http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/.

Good luck!